# struct/union initialization confusion

Tags: c, struct, unions

I'm currently doing practice exams for a test I will have next monday and I came across something that confused me!

I have the following structs:

```
struct shape2d {
   float x;
   float y;
};

struct shape3d {
   struct shape2d base;
   float z;
};

struct shape {
   int dimensions;
   char *name;
   union {
      struct shape2d s1;
      struct shape3d s2;
   } description;
};

typedef struct shape Shape;
```

I have to make a function that 'creates' a shape with the following signature:

```
Shape *createShape3D(float x, float y, float z, char *name);
```

Because I'm dealing with an union of structs, I'm not quite sure how to initialize all the fields I need!

Here's what I have so far:

```
Shape *createShape3D(float x, float y, float z, char *name) {
   Shape *s = (Shape *) malloc(sizeof(Shape));
   s->dimensions = 3;
   s->name = "Name..."; 

   // How can I initialize s2? 

   return s;
}
```

Any help would be apprectiated!

Comment: It seems a bit odd to describe a 2D or 3D point as a 'shape'.  And you might decide that `description` is an awfully long name, too.  If you have [C2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), you could consider using an anonymous union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 s->description.s2.base.x=1;
 s->description.s2.base.y=2;
 s->description.s2.z=3;
```

As you can see, the syntax gets a little heavy at times, so it may make sense to define functions for accessing individual coordinates off a pointer to the structure:

```
float getX(Shape *s) {
    if (dimensions == 2) {
        return s->structure.s1.x;
    } else {
        return s->structure.s2.base.x;
    }
}
void setX(Shape *s, float x) {
    if (dimensions == 2) {
        s->structure.s1.x = x;
    } else {
        s->structure.s2.base.x = x;
    }
}
// Define similar functions for Y and Z
```

Now your initialization routine would change to more readable

```
setX(s, 1);
setY(s, 2);
setZ(s, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to strcpy name to s->name.

```
strcpy(s->name, "Name ...");
```

You can initialize s2 as

```
s->description.s2.z = 0;
s->description.s2.base.x = 0;
s->description.s2.base.y = 0;
```

You can read up more on unions in a book. You can also look here

http://c-faq.com/struct/union.html

http://c-faq.com/struct/initunion.html

http://c-faq.com/struct/taggedunion.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape *createShape3D(float x, float y, float z, char *name) {
   Shape *s = (Shape *) malloc(sizeof(Shape));
   s->dimensions = 3;
   s->name = malloc (strlen(name) + 1);
   strcpy(s->name, name); // Copy the value of name
   s->description.s2.base.x = x;
   s->description.s2.base.y = y;
   s->description.s2.z = z;

   return s;
}
```

Also make sure to free up the memory for `s->name` before freeing up `Shape* s`

Comment: You have a memory leak for s->name

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that, I had merely copied the content from the user's post and just wanted to show how to set the values for `x`, `y` and `z`. Anyways updated the answer with setting `name` too.

Comment: Now, accepting the return of strcpy back in s->name is redundant.

Comment: Thanks! Another typo, fixed now.